# back() redirect with flash message after login with socialite laravel

Tags: laravel, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

call back route: (I test it with google)

```
Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function (){
    $this->get('login/{provider}/callback', 'LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
    ...
}
```

in the LoginController class

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

and callback function

```
    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider)
    {
      $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
      $user = User::whereEmail($social_user->getEmail())->first();
      auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
      $request->session()->flash('alert', 'hello '.$user->name;);
      return back();
    }
```

It always redirect to home page and without `alert` session.

I found because of this code in

> app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
            return redirect('/home');
}
```

how can do it? I want run this piece of code

```
$request->session()->flash('alert', 'hello '.$user->name;);
return back();
```

not this:

```
return redirect('/home');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out `'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,` line in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file and you won't be having that redirect